# Different expressions...how to turn from one to another?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to turn $$(x-2)^{-2/3}-{x\cdot(2/3)\cdot(x-2)^{-5/3}}$$ to $$\frac{x-6}{3(x-2)^{5/3}}$$
I did common denominator but with no use...

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}(x-2)^{-2/3}-x\cdot (2/3)\cdot (x-2)^{-5/3}&=\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2/3}}-\frac{2x}{3(x-2)^{5/3}}\\&=\frac{3(x-2)^{3/3}}{(x-2)^{2/3}\cdot 3(x-2)^{3/3}}-\frac{2x}{3(x-2)^{5/3}}\\&=\frac{3(x-2)-2x}{3(x-2)^{5/3}}\\&=\frac{x-6}{3(x-2)^{5/3}}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $$(x-2)^{-2/3}=(x-2)^{-5/3}(x-2)$$